# Moving the position of header top links

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2, header, toplinks

I am trying to change the position of top links. I want to move `top.menu` before `top.links`.
In my `page.xml` following code is given:

```
            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
            </block>
```

And I have changed it as following to move `top.menu` above:

```
            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
            </block>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are `child block` of `header` so you you have to change it in `app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/template/page/html/header.php` change position of this child block `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu')  ?>` move before `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below code

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" before="top.links" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks" after="top.menu"/>
                <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
            </block>
```

**Hope this will help you!**

Comment: Exactly, I have done this but it doesn't work. I have cleared cache.